# native app login/session security concerns

Tags: session, authentication, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm currently building a native app using angular 2 and NativeScript for the first time. my concern is about the authentication and session process. I know that when developing on for the web you have issues like xss attacks and man-in-the-middle attacks, but what are the main concerns to look out for when authenticating someone via a database on a remote server in native apps?

what are the web security variabilities native equivalents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat any client (be it a NativeScript Mobile App, a Cordova App, a native Windows App or whatever) exactly the same as you would a Web App when it comes to network traffic (such as a login process). The Web browser is just another client which doesn't differ from other clients in this aspect.

This means that MITM-attacks are just as easy/hard to perform no matter if it's a website or a NativeScript App. Same thing goes with storing sensitive keys on the device. E.g. if your login mechanisms rely on a secret on the device, treat that secret as something which can easily be extracted from the source code, just as if it was a Javascript file on a web page.

As long as you, in your app, don't `eval` code there's no specific things to look out for security-wise.

Answer (score 0):

you can add crypto functions to a nativescript app:

- https://github.com/brix/crypto-js
- https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-encryption